# A query using Spring Data sets the transaction to rollback only but I'm not sure why

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, eclipselink

This is my `@Repository` interface with the native query:

```
@Repository
public interface RecentPersonRepository extends JpaRepository<RecentPerson, Long>{
@Query(value = "select id, person_id, unique_sc_id, unique_c_id, person_first_name, person_last_name, viewed_date, dob from recent_person where person_id = ?1  order by viewed_date desc", nativeQuery = true)
List<RecentPerson> getRecentPersons(String adjusterId);
```

}

This method is called by another method that has a `@Transactional` annotation.  The call to `getRecentPersons()`, in the inner working of Spring, calls `setRollbackOnly(true)` causing the rest of the transaction to fail.  The call to `getRecentPersons()` actually completes and returns the correct results but when the transaction is committed later the method fails because the transaction was set to rollback during the query method.

Spring calls `setRollbackOnly` somewhere where it is dealing with parameters but I am passing a single value to the method and the method actually completes even though it was set to rollback only causing the rest of the method to fail.

Is there something wrong with my query?  Or is there a problem because it is `native=true` or something?

Below is the exception that causes the rollback and the stacktrace that ends up calling `setRollbackOnly`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No parameter with index : 1 was found within the query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=RecentPerson sql="select id, person_id, unique_sc_id, unique_c_id, person_first_name, person_last_name, viewed_date, dob from recent_person where person_id = ?1  order by viewed_date desc").


setRollbackOnly:862, QueryImpl (org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa)
getParameter:966, QueryImpl (org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa)
getBindingFor:80, StringQueryParameterBinder (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query)
bind:60, StringQueryParameterBinder (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query)
bind:101, ParameterBinder (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query)
bind:76, SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query)
bindAndPrepare:161, ParameterBinder (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query)
bindAndPrepare:152, ParameterBinder (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query)
doCreateQuery:81, AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query)
createQuery:190, AbstractJpaQuery (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query)
doExecute:123, JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query)
execute:87, JpaQueryExecution (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query)
doExecute:116, AbstractJpaQuery (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query)
execute:106, AbstractJpaQuery (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query)
doInvoke:492, RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor (org.springframework.data.repository.core.support)
invoke:475, RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor (org.springframework.data.repository.core.support)
proceed:179, ReflectiveMethodInvocation (org.springframework.aop.framework)
invoke:56, DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor (org.springframework.data.projection)
proceed:179, ReflectiveMethodInvocation (org.springframework.aop.framework)
proceedWithInvocation:99, TransactionInterceptor$1 (org.springframework.transaction.interceptor)
invokeWithinTransaction:282, TransactionAspectSupport (org.springframework.transaction.interceptor)
invoke:96, TransactionInterceptor (org.springframework.transaction.interceptor)
proceed:179, ReflectiveMethodInvocation (org.springframework.aop.framework)
invoke:136, PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor (org.springframework.dao.support)
proceed:179, ReflectiveMethodInvocation (org.springframework.aop.framework)
invoke:133, CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support)
proceed:179, ReflectiveMethodInvocation (org.springframework.aop.framework)
invoke:92, ExposeInvocationInterceptor (org.springframework.aop.interceptor)
proceed:179, ReflectiveMethodInvocation (org.springframework.aop.framework)
invoke:57, SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor (org.springframework.data.repository.core.support)
proceed:179, ReflectiveMethodInvocation (org.springframework.aop.framework)
invoke:213, JdkDynamicAopProxy (org.springframework.aop.framework)
getRecentPersons:-1, $Proxy193 (com.sun.proxy)
addRecentPerson:235, PersonService (com.blah.portal.services.web.service)
invoke:-1, PersonService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$50ca8ee8 (com.blah.portal.services.web.service)
invoke:204, MethodProxy (org.springframework.cglib.proxy)
invokeJoinpoint:738, CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation (org.springframework.aop.framework)
proceed:157, ReflectiveMethodInvocation (org.springframework.aop.framework)
proceedWithInvocation:99, TransactionInterceptor$1 (org.springframework.transaction.interceptor)
invokeWithinTransaction:282, TransactionAspectSupport (org.springframework.transaction.interceptor)
invoke:96, TransactionInterceptor (org.springframework.transaction.interceptor)
proceed:179, ReflectiveMethodInvocation (org.springframework.aop.framework)
intercept:673, CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor (org.springframework.aop.framework)
addRecentPerson:-1, PersonService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$372034be (com.blah.portal.services.web.service)
addRecentPerson:49, PersonController (com.blah.portal.services.web.controller)
```

Versions

```
org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.13.10.RELEASE
org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.11.10.RELEASE

org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.7.1
org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.1.1
org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa:2.4.2
org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql:2.4.2
```

Comment: Why do you have Eclipselink:2.7.1 with org.eclipse.persistence.jpa:2.4.2?  You are using 2.4.1 EclipseLink JPA implementation classes over the 2.7.1 core classes.  Just use 2.7.1 and you won't see QueryImpl calling setRollbackOnly.

Comment: I thought that was weird to have the franken mishmash of library versions but I wasn't sure it could cause this problem.  I added an explicit dependency to 2.7.1 jpa classes and the problem was solved.  Thanks!!